# Update/add username in url in python

Tags: python, urllib, urlparse

If I have a URL (ex: "ssh://hello@xyz.com:553/random_uri", "https://test.blah.blah:993/random_uri2"), I want to set/update the username in the url.
I know there is urllib.parse.urlparse (https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) that would break them down but I am having trouble creating a new url (or updating) the parsed result with the username I intend to use.

Is there any python library that can help set/update username?  Preferably using the parsed result of an urlparse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way to do this: https://sdqali.in/blog/2017/09/25/python-url-manipulation-revisited/
Can create a 'furl' object, set username, and get updated url string.

Comment: I would have gone the simple way:  `url_text.replace('https://', 'https://user@pass')`

Comment: Yeah, good option as well, though sometimes i expect there to be a 'user' included in the url, though a good regex should take care of it.

Comment: The linked site is now offline and not found in the Internet Archive. It would have been more useful for posterity to record the actual steps here.

Answer (score 2):

Python [urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) does not have a nice method to set/edit or remove username/password from URLs.
However, you can use the `netloc` attribute. See the example function below.

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse, quote

def set_url_username_password(url, username, password):
  _username = quote(username)
  _password = quote(password)
  _url = urlparse(url)
  _netloc = _url.netloc.split('@')[-1]
  _url = _url._replace(netloc=f'{_username}:{_password}@{_netloc}')
  return _url.geturl()

original_url = 'https://google.com'
username = 'username'
password = 'pa$$word'
new_url = set_url_username_password(original_url, username, password)
```

`new_url` will be set to `https://username:pa%24%24word@google.com`.

Note that this function replaces any existing credentials with the new ones.

Here is a bonus function to remove credentials from an URL:

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse

def unset_url_username_password(url):
  _url = urlparse(url)
  _netloc = _url.netloc.split('@')[-1]
  _url = _url._replace(netloc=_netloc)
  return _url.geturl()
```

Comment: You can use `_url.hostname` instead of `_url.netloc.split('@')[-1]`

Answer (score 1):

Let me to show a script without 3rd package.

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

old_url = "https://user:password@search-books-edupractice.es.amazonaws.com"
user="user-01"
password="my-secure-password"

_url = urlparse(old_url)
domain = _url.netloc.split("@")[-1]
new_url = "{}://{}:{}@{}".format(_url.scheme, user,password, domain)
```

Run the script, the variable `new_url` contains your url with new user and password.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option that retains everything in the input URL (just adds or updates the auth), using stdlib only:

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlunparse


def inject_auth_to_url(url: str, user: str, password: str) -> str:
    parsed = urlparse(url)
    
    # works no matter if the original url had a user/pass or not
    domain = parsed.netloc.split("@")[-1]
    domain = f"{user}:{password}@{domain}"

    unparsed = (parsed[0], domain, parsed[2], parsed[3], parsed[4], parsed[5])

    return urlunparse(unparsed)
```